# Java - connecting SQL Server DB: Class not found

Tags: java, sql-server, class

I am trying to establish a link between my SQL-Server DB and my java program.

At the moment I got the following code:

```
    package Spike;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class sqltest {
        public static void main(String[] args){


            try {
                String username = "xx";
                String password = "xxxxx";

                String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;databaseName=Sqltest";

                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

                if (conn != null) {
                    System.out.println("Connected");
                }

            }catch (ClassNotFoundException cne){
                System.out.println("Class not found!");
            }catch (SQLException sqle){
                System.out.println("SQL Exception!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I masked out the username and password. But it gives me the Class not Found error. I tried all different paths but nothing seems to be working.
Anyone has a idea?

Comment: Think you miss the  jar containing the Driver in classpath: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver

Comment: please post stack trace with error

Comment: I can't find how to add the driver to my program?

Comment: I tried adding them to the library and not I got a SQLexception